# Counting Failed Jobs in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I know that to count the size of a queue in Laravel, I can use `Queue::size('queue_name')`. Is there something similar to get a count of *failed* jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you created the failed-jobs table? Do so by executing this:

```
php artisan queue:failed-table
```

Once you have that table, you can easily count it or query it however you like.

[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs)

Answer (score 1):

Failed jobs are saved to the `failed_jobs` table that you can create with Laravel migrations. One option is to count the number of failed jobs by retrieving the number of records. See https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs